# Google drive integrate login redirect_uri_mismatch error in ios sdk

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I try to integrate google drive in ios sdk using [this](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit) project, but got error after login. 
please help how to solve this error

[image]

Comment: use correct bundle Identifier.

Answer (score 1):

The redirect URI needs to be registered in the APIs console, and the error is indicating that you haven't done that, or haven't done it correctly.

Go to the console for your project, check the API Access settings and make sure that URL is one of the Redirect URIs. If the URI you want isn't listed, click edit settings and add the URI to the list.

Answer (score 0):

use correct bundle Identifier.check bundle Identifier.